# jquery hide for multiple divs classes with IDs appended to end

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have multiple sections as divs, each with a number appended to the end of the id(id="section-'.$section.'"). There could be many of these and the id would increment each time.

I am trying to write a jquery script to show and hide the correct id="resource-'.$section.'".
When the user clicks on the img inside the section div, it will show hide the appropriate resource div and hide all others.

```
<div id="section-'.$section.'">
<img src="" id="section-img-'.$section.'"/>
</div>

<div id="resource-'.$section.'"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#resource").hide();
      jQuery("#section img").click(function()
           {
              jQuery(this).next("#resource").show();
           });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas or help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

---

modification:

```
<div class="section" id="section-'.$section.'">
    <img src="" class="section-img" id="section-img-'.$section.'"/>
        </div>


    <div class="resource" id="resource-'.$section.'"></div>
```

---

[jsfiddle.net/kqQDH/1](http://jsfiddle.net/kqQDH/1)

Comment: `jQuery("#resource")` will only match an element with _exactly_ `id="resource"` -- nothing else appended to it. You cannot have that hypen in the attribute and have that style of selector work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.resource').hide();
    jQuery('.section-img').click(function() {
        jQuery('.resource').hide(); //hide others

        //parse id for index
        var idx = jQuery(this).attr("id").split('-')[2];
        jQuery('#resource-'+idx).show(); //show this
    });
});​
```

---

A `class` is not an `id`. They are two completely different html attributes; classes need not be unique -- and in fact your jQuery class selector relies on them not being so.

```
<div id="section-1" class="section" >
<img src="" id="section-img-1" class="section-img" />
</div>

<div id="resource-1" class="resource"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('div[id^="resource"]').hide();
      jQuery('div[id^="section-img"]').click(function()
           {
              jQuery(this).parent().next('div[id^="resource"]').show();
           });
});
</script>​​​​​​
```

Note if you decide the previous structure of your classnames was necessary (for whatever reason), then you won't be able to use a class selector -- you will have to use an attribute starts-with selector.

It would be better if you assigned the elements ids as well as a class indicating what kind of element it is. e.g The first section would be `<div id="section-1" class="section"></div>`. Then you could select all `section`s at once with a simple class selector, or do something specific to one using its id.

Comment: i know a class is not an id and that they are different html attributes. and i know classes need not be unique. Read my question as you have not even attempted to answer it :(

Comment: @Codded Dude tell me one thing in one section would there be only image and regarding resource ?

Comment: @codded Sorry, I may not have been clear. `.resource` will only match the class name `resource`. Not a class name that _starts with_ resource. Note the changes I made to your html to make those class names valid.

Comment: cant get this to work, i have formatted html as you have. All resource divs are hidden but img click does nothing.

Comment: @codded I made another change to it -- there is no next `resource` immediately following the img, so you have to get the next after its parent. It should work fine now.

Comment: @codded updated and it's working - see changes. Sorry jsfiddle seems to be down, I'll give you a working link soon

Comment: How can i implement a focus on div, so if the user clicks on the section img it auto scrolls to <div id="resource-1" class="resource"></div>

Comment: @codded Try `$("#resource-1").focus()`. Otherwise it's just as easy to append the # to the url and have the browser scroll for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you follow the below scenario :
put all the sections in a div#sections, and your resources in a div#resources
then get the index of the parent of clicked image then show the resource having this index.

your code may look like :

```
<div id="sections">
   <div class="section">
      <img src="" class="section-img"/>
   </div>
   ...
</div>

<div id="resources">
   <div class="resource"></div>
   ....
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  $('.section-img').click(function(){ var index = $(this).parent().index();  $('.resource').hide().filter(':eq('+index+')').show()  })  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) your current `.resource` and `.section` selectors will fail because there are no elements with precisely those classes - as you say, the classes are `.section-4` for example, not just `.section`.

2) The `next()` command will fail because it's running from the context of the `img` tag, but in fact the `.resource` DIV is a sibling of the parent `.section` DIV

Harmonise your class names to be general, and if things really need unique IDs, use an `id` attribute for that. So, HTML:

```
<!-- classes generalised; add in unique IDs as required -->
<div class="section">
    <img src="" class="section-img" />
</div>
<div class="resource"></div>
```

There, the class names are consistent and not unique. This makes the JS part much simpler.

```
jQuery(".resource").hide();
jQuery(".section img").click(function() {
    jQuery(this).parent().next(".resource").show(); //<-- note, parent()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, if the class name is going to vary as per the number, you must assign it to ID of the div. Assuming that, here is the solution:

```
    $('img[id^="section-"]').click (function (e) {
  var temp_section = $(this).attr('id').replace('section-','');
      $('#resource-'+temp_section).show();
      $('div[id^="resource-"]').css("display","none");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time an image is clicked, you need to parse its number from the class and then find the correct div with the resource class:

```
jQuery(".section img").click(function()
 {
     //1.Hide all resources
     jQuery('div[class^="resource"]').hide();

     //2. parse number of resource to show   
     var number = parseInt($(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)$/)[0], 10);
     var resourceClass = ".resource-" + number; 

     //3.find resource class and show it
     jQuery(resourceClass).show();
 });
```

I didn't test it so there might be some typing errors, but if i get your meaning this is the direction you want.

Comment: still not managing, i have tried your method with no avail: http://jsfiddle.net/kqQDH/1/

Comment: Unfortunatley, i cannot access jsfiddle :( what exactly isn't working?

Comment: its ok sorted it with help from @nbrooks